# Create a path to write a text file

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I have code that responds to a button. This code works, but I want to know how to change the path to something other than MyDocuments. How would I do this? Do I need to create the file path first. e.g. `c:\TextFiles\myfile.txt`?

```
Private Sub Button28_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button28.Click
    Dim dataLine As String
    Dim mydocpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Using outputFile As New StreamWriter(mydocpath & Convert.ToString("\DataLines.txt"))
        For Each p As PointF In lstECRPairs(106)
            dataLine = p.X & " / " & p.Y
            outputFile.WriteLine(dataLine)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you converting a string to a string? `Convert.ToString("\DataLines.txt")`

Comment: @VisualVincent just to be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct if you just add the full path and file name in the streamwriter that will write the file there.

```
Private Sub Button28_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button28.Click
Dim dataLine As String
'YourFilePathAndFileName
Using outputFile As New StreamWriter(c:\TextFiles\myfile.txt)
    For Each p As PointF In lstECRPairs(106)
        dataLine = p.X & " / " & p.Y
        outputFile.WriteLine(dataLine)
    Next
End Using
End Sub
```

Also the below line is getting the myDocs. You don't need it unless you wanted to copy to MYDocuments.

```
Dim mydocpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine. I just had to create the folder first.

Comment: Can you make which ever answer as answered for others.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `SaveFileDialog` method.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dataLine As String
    Dim mydocpath As String
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        mydocpath = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        Using outputFile As New StreamWriter(mydocpath & Convert.ToString("\DataLines.txt"))
            For Each p As PointF In lstECRPairs(106)
                dataLine = p.X & " / " & p.Y
                outputFile.WriteLine(dataLine)
            Next
        End Using
    Else
        ''nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

I didnt add the details of the `SaveFileDialog` You can edit them in the solution explorer or if you really need, i can edit my answer to help with it.
I haven't been able to test if, however it should do the trick :)